# Writing \t to a file from user input

Tags: c#

I have just started learning C# and now I'm experimenting with File IO. I am having some problem writing a <kbd>tab</kbd> (`\t`) character to the file.

This is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", input));
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Shashank\Desktop\test.txt", input);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run the script and input this text:

```
hello \twhat \tis \tyour name
```

The following gets written to my file:

```
hello
\twhat
\tis
\tyour
name
```

But, I want the file output to look like:

```
hello
    what
    is
    your
name
```

I have already looked online but cannot find a solution that gives me the desired result. I also tried using `StreamWriter` but to no avail.

Comment: do you want a tab or 4 spaces?

Comment: Replace the /t s with four spaces....

Comment: @Fredou, I want a tab

Comment: Well if you want  tab your code is working. How many spaces a tab takes up would depend on how the app you are opening the file up in interprets a tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a method for unescaping strings in .NET, although perhaps not where you expect it:

[Regex.Unescape(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(@"\tHello\nWorld"));
```

will result in (depending on your tab indentation setting):

```
    Hello
World
```

So, if you want to unescape your input string and then split it into individual strings (lines) for output, you can do something like this:

```
string[] input = Regex.Unescape( Console.ReadLine() ).Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", input));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Shashank\Desktop\test.txt", input);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Or, you could first split and then unescape (using Linq):

```
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(Regex.Unescape).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", input));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Shashank\Desktop\test.txt", input);
Console.ReadKey();
```

If your intention is to treat sequences of spaces as a single delimiter, then use:

`input.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: This is by far the most elegant and concise method. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sshashank124, yes, and it is well hidden ;)

Comment: @Silvermind, it is about **Unescaping**. Provide an example to make your argument more clear, please.

Comment: @Silvermind, Yes, and it does so not only with the "(" (look at the documentation i linked to in my answer). But why should this be of practical concern here in the context of the question?

Answer (score 8):

`"\t"` is representation of tab only when used in string literal. When it is just an input string, there is nothing that interprets the two characters `\` and `t` in any special way (same for all other escape sequences).

You can replace them yourself with [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Replace(@"\t", "\t").Split(' ')
```

Comment: Is there no way of doing it automatically or do I have to do it explicitly

Comment: @sshashank124 There is no existing method in .Net framework I know of that will do replacement matching rules for string literal values.

Comment: Just another question. Is there a way of doing such replacements explicitly for all the escape sequences `\t\r\n\b` etc? Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @sshashank124 Check out elgonzo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the console is escaping \t for you, that is, the input looks like "hello \twhat \tis \tyour name". Can be solved by replacing "\t" with "\t" using string.Replace().

```
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
string text = string.Join("\n", input).Replace("\\t", "\t");
Console.WriteLine(text);
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test.txt", text);
Console.ReadKey();
```

You might want to use Environment.NewLine instead of "\n".